# moving images in visual studio c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My program consists of a grid with 8 images (one free space). At the moment when you click on one image and then another they swap, but I only want the image to move one space at a time and only if there is a clear box. (like those scramble games)

I have this swap method, but how can I change it to fit what I want?

```
string click1Name="";
string click1Loc="";
string click2Name="";
string click2Loc="";

private void swap()
{ 
var objName=(Image)this.FindName(click1Loc);
objName.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Pic1/"+click2Name));
objName = (Image)this.FindName(click2Loc);
objName.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Pic1/" + click1Name));
}
```

GridPic9 is the free space (Pic9.jpg)

Comment: A more typical solution would probably be to move the UI elements around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of what your problem is. I'm guessing when you click over one Image, you load its name and location into the corresponding global variables (`click(x)Name` and `click(x)Loc`); and then, when you click over the second Image, you load again name and location, and call `Swap` afterwards. Is that it?

In order to manage the swapping constrains that you stated, I would create a matrix of objects. Each object would contain info about what is shown in each Image control. The following is a naive way to do it, but it can give you an idea.

```cs
    class ImageInfo
    {
         public string Name;
         Image AssociatedControl;
         

        public ImageInfo(string name, string loc)
        {
           Name=name; 
           AssociatedControl=(Image)this.FindName(loc);
           DisplayToControl();
        }

        void DisplayToControl()
        {
           if(Name!=null)
               AssociatedControl.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Pic1/"+Name));
           else
              AssociatedControl.Source =null;
         }

        
        public void SetImage(string name)
        {
            Name=name;
            DisplayToControl()
        }
    }

    ImageInfo[][] myImagesLayout = new ImageInfo[3][3];
    Tuple<int,int> PreviousClickedImageCoords = null;

    void myWindow_Load()
    {
      //Initialize the 8 images in their initial positions
       myImagesLayout [0][0] = new myImagesLayout(name1,location1);
       //[...]
       myImagesLayout [2][1] = new myImagesLayout(name8,location8);
       myImagesLayout [2][2] = new myImagesLayout(null,location9);
    }

    
    void Image1_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Clicked(0,0);
    }

    //[...]

     void Image9_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Clicked(2,2);
    }

    void Clicked(int row, int column)
    {
        if(PreviousClickedImageCoords == null )
        {
            if(myImagesLayout[row][column].Name!=null)
                 PreviousClickedImageCoords = new Tuple<int,int>(row,column);
        }
        else
        {
            if(myImagesLayout[row][column].Name!=null)
               return; //only to empty images

           int prevRow=PreviousClickedImageCoords.Item1;
           int prevCol=PreviousClickedImageCoords.Item2;
            
           int step = Math.Abs(Row-prevRow) + Math.Abs(Col-prevCol);

           if(step!=1)
              return; //only adjacent cells. No diagonals 
            
           ImageInfo PreviousClickedImage = myImagesLayout[prevRow][prevCol];
           myImagesLayout[row][column].SetImage(PreviousClickedImage.Name);
           PreviousClickedImage.SetImage(null);
           PreviousClickedImage=null;

         }
     }
```